# Can ions of a pure substance be obtained in only gaseous form?

Tags: mass-spectrometry, ionization-energy

I was studying mass spectrometry where I learned that the sample is first vaporized before ionization. And ions are formed in gaseous from in an ionization chamber.

Why is there need of vapourizing our sample first? Can't we directly ionize the solid sample without vapourizing it?

Comment: It depends on what is being analyzed. Possibly [sputtering.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sputtering) could be used.

Comment: Maybe look up techniques like LIBS (laser induced breakdown spectroscopy), being used on Mars for zapping rocks to determine elemental composition.

Comment: Once the molecules are in the gaseous phase (well, vacuum), the molecules are isolated from neighboring molecules and ions which would allow to "return" to the neuter, uncharged state. What could be alternatives to accelerate them than as a charged item in an electric field and separate them by electromagnets (in case you use a sector field MS)?  Even the [MALDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix-assisted_laser_desorption/ionization)-(TOF)-MS rely on an ionization of the desorbed molecules.

Comment: The point of ionization is that you can readily separate charged species based on charge to mass ratio. Separation is much more difficult for neutral species (but certainly not impossible). So for MS to work you need to both bring the species into the gas phase *and* ionize them. You seem to wonder whether you might ionize first and then bring the ions to the gas phase, or maybe do both things simultaneously. Is that right? Otherwise it seems unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Ok i got the points. Thanx much. But as ionization energy is defined as energy required to remive an electron from an isolated gaseous atom. Then all the metals or element in solid form in periodic table are first vapourized and then their ionization energies are determined experimentally?. Like ionization energy of Na metal is determined in it's vapour form??

Answer (score 3):

Consider that ions, by definition, have an electric charge. If you have ions in a matrix, e.g. table salt, $\ce{NaCl}$, crystals, the negative and positive charges balance. and the ions can get cozy. But **pure** ions, e.g. $\ce{Na+}$ or $\ce{Cl-}$, do not find each other attractive enough for a really solid relationship.

As an exercise, calculate the repulsive force of ions in condensed matter, e.g. a hypothetical $\ce{Na+}$ crystal *sans* balancing $\ce{Cl-}$ ions... you might be surprised at its strength.

That said, a small number of ions can be **trapped** in a crystal, as [point defects](https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/def_en/kap_2/illustr/t2_1_2.html). [Electromagnetic radiation spectroscopy](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/UV-visible-absorption-spectra-of-the-pristine-and-130-MeV-Ni-and-150-MeV-Ag-ion_fig5_251572330) *can* be used, though since they're surrounded by other species, the light spectra are not those of the *pure* ion. As for *mass* spectroscopy, it would be hard to get an ion trapped in a solid to move in a magnetic or electrostatic field, though not impossible. Perhaps you might explore this in heated ionic crystals with point defects?